# date recorded on iPhone 4 from camera or phone?

Tags: iphone

when sending a pic from nikkon camera to iPhone 4, will the date recorded be the one taken from the camera or the current date on the iPhone 4?

Answer (score 3):

The data will be that which was written to the original metadata taken on your Nikon camera. Unless of course you're doing some kind of image conversion or editing on your phone, then something could change.